# org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportListener

Tags: jar, wso2, wso2-esb

I try to activate the SAP interface in ESB 4.9.0 but I got an exception during the Axis2.xml loading while starting up.
After an investigation I found out that the necessary org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap_1.0.0.jar (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/SAP+Integration)   from  /repository/components/plugins directory  is missing.

Is there a reason for it? where can I get this JAR from?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully integrated the wso2 esb 4.8.1 with sap like described here (BAPI & Idoc).

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/SAP+Integration

The jar your refering to is located in esb 4.8.1 under the following directories.

wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\components\plugins

wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\components\patches\patch0000

Maybe it's the same for 4.9. version, but I'm not sure.

What kind of error you're getting?

Comment: I tried to find the JAR even in patches folder but simply is not part of the ESB 4.9 (neither 5.0 beta) at all! the error which I get is this       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v14

Comment: I downloaded ESB 4.8.1 and the SAP jar is referenced there on several places. It looks to me like the SAP support has not been included in ESB 4.9 + on purpose. any idea?

Comment: Sorry no clue why it's not there. According to the documentation it should it be.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by installing the SAP adapter as a new feature (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Installing+Features)

I do not know why, but the apter is available only for 4.8.1 and older versions, hence I had to use them as the repository.